# php chamar html com class

Tags: php, classes, div

```css
   .up{
 color: #80006F;
}

.up:hover{
color: #CC00B1;
}

input{
margin-top:20px ; 
margin-left:0px ; 
margin-right:5px ;
margin-bottom:10px ;

}
.modal-header{
background: ;

}


@font-face {

  font-family: "polya";
  src: url("polya.otf")format("truetype");

  }


.amigo{
font-family: "polya";  
font-size: 100px;
   } 

#brand{
width: 30px;
height: auto;
}



.rodape{
background-color: #000;
margin: 0;
padding-right: 18px;
text-align: center;

}

img{
width: 20%;
}

li{
padding-right: 200px;
padding-left: 50px;

}

a{

font-size: 20px;

}

.Img{
width: 10%;
}
```

Problema provavelmente bem simples, só não sei como implementar. Eu estou tentando criar coisas de html com o php e eu queria configurar o tamanho de uma imagem com a classe dele e chamar em php. Problema é que quando chamo ele em classe ele parece ignorar a classe e roda sem a configuração.

```
            $result_produto = "SELECT * FROM produto";
        $resultado_produto = mysqli_query($conn, $result_produto);
        while($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produto)){
            echo "ID: " . $row_produto['ID']. "<br>";
            echo "Nome do produto: " . $row_produto['Nome_produto']. "<br>";
            echo "Preço: " . $row_produto['Preco_produto']. "<br>";
            echo "Descrição do produto: " . $row_produto['Descricao_produto']. "<br>";
            foreach($imagem as $imagem){
            echo  '<img src="'.$imagem.'" class="Img"/>';
            }
        }
```

Comment: Se no CSS tiver a classe `.Img` deveria ser aplicada normalmente.

Comment: Tem algo que poderia estar errado ? pq eu já mudei varias vezes o nome da class e realmente não vai =/

Comment: coloque o arquivo css na sua questão, verifique se as classes estão de acordo e pressione `CTRL + J` e depois `F5`, pode ser cache....

Comment: é ... realmente não funciona, ele até vai quando dou inspecionar e configuro mas agora no css ele nem chega a chamar

Comment: Coloque o arquivo css em sua questão.

Comment: pronto, acho que era assim que queria

Comment: Faz do jeito errado : altere essa linha `'<img src="'.$imagem.'" class="Img"/>';` para `'<img src="'.$imagem.'" class="Img" style="width: 10%";/>';`, se realmente quer aprender e tirar melhor proveito da comunidade considere ler a [help] e executar as orientações que aqueles que querem lhe ajudar pedem... Coloque o arquivo css inteiro, não o que você espera como resultado...

Comment: Deste jeito que pediu para eu testar realmente funcionou

Comment: Você tá implementando o css no arquivo PHP? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="[ARQUIVO CSS]">`

Comment: tô sim, até re-escrevi por achar estar errado

Comment: Eu fiz oque o Magic passou e tinha funcionado mas fui inspecionar a pagina e ele começou a chamar a class certo, após eu tirar o style para ver se a class começou a funcionar, vi que realmente estava chamando, mudei o valor da class pra ver se alterava mas ele buga, é como se o código n atualizasse mais, só quando se muda algo como no caso o style

Comment: ele está funcionando certo agora com o css chamando certinho, só tem um delay do php mesmo apertando o f5, eu acho... acho que é um bug do php pq não mudei nada no código alem do style que o Magic pediu pra alterar e depois que tirei esse style o css pegou normal

Comment: Cada requisição do HTTP é uma pedido diferente. Você deve atualizar com Ctrl+F5 ou apertar enter na barra de endereços. Deve funcionar melhor que um simples F5. O ctrl+F5 recarrega a página sem nem tocar no cache kk

Comment: @Breno por isso falei para mandar um `CTRL + J` antes...Só mão falei para selecionar `disable cache`... mas tá bom ele chega lá...

Comment: muito obrigado kkkk... tenho muito oque aprender ainda. Só fiquei encucado pq eu fiz isso do CTRL + J depois F5 mesmo assim não tinha funcionado. mas sempre vou fazer isso daqui por diante pq pra atualizar eu só ia no link e dava enter mesmo. Muito obrigado aos dois =)